# res.end() is not a fuction problem on nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var myHTTP = require('http');
var myServer = myHTTP.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (res.url == "/")
        res.end('Welcome');
});
myServer.listen(4000);

console.log('Server Runs Successfully')
```

*First it showing the console.log but after when checking in the browser it showing problem loading page and an error rise in terminal which is down below.*

**TypeError: res.end is not a function**

*I couldn't find the problem in the code is it any syntax error or problem on the installation file of node js*.

Comment: This is not an answer but shouldn't it be req.url?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end

Comment: yes bro , thanks . i got it

Comment: @TusharShahi you made my day , thanks a lot

Comment: Did changing res.url to req.url fix it? That's it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
res.status(200).end(Json.Stringify(data));
return;
```